# Old Literature Stack Exchange migration links no longer work properly

Tags: bug, migration, hyperlinks

I've been browsing elsewhere on Stack Exchange, and I noticed that a few questions that have been migrated redirect to Literature via their post numbers - as they should. An example is [What order should the Chronicles of Narnia books be read in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15841/41082), on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange. There is a link on the notice, which normally leads you back to the original question (and its revision history):

[image]

The issue seems to be that the link redirects via question ID. That link brings you to the page `https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/2/revisions` - which now redirects to the revisions of [a totally different Literature question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2/71). Another case I've seen is, of course, [Why did Literature fail?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131397/274942).

I don't know how widespread this is, or how many questions were migrated, but I'm assuming that this is not the desired behavior, and could end up getting confusing.

---

Playing around, I noticed that old chat oneboxing also sends you to the wrong questions (starting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037/2011/8/9)). I don't think that's going to be an issue, but it does show that there are various other ways in which the ID links fail.

Comment: Ouch. This is a nasty edge case - I hope it's possible to deal with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you come across these, flag 'em and ask a moderator to clear the migration history.

We were supposed to do that when shutting the site down, but it's possible we either forgot or these were migrated prior to the shutdown event.